# How to check if a variable of an object in an ArrayList is equal to any of the same variables of the other objects in the ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I have an ArrayList of the Class `ZombieSprite` in my `GameView` class which includes all  my `ZombieSprites`. In my `ZombieSprite` class i have the method `getDirection()`. Now i dont want the `ZombieSprites` to collide. So need to check if the variable `x` of the object `thezombiesprite` id the `ArrayList` is equal to any other variable `x` of an object `thezombiesprite` in the `ArrayList`.

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {
  // not interesting 
  List<ZombieSprite> zombieSpriteList = new ArrayList<ZombieSprite>();
  // not interesting

public class ZombieSprite {
    private int x = 0;
private int y = 0;
  private void getDirection() {
    if (x < PlayerSprite.x) {
        x = x + xSpeed;
    }
    if (x > PlayerSprite.x) {
        x = x - xSpeed;
    }
    if (x == PlayerSprite.x) {
        x = x;
    }
    if (y < PlayerSprite.y) {
        y = y + ySpeed + backgroundspeed;
    }
    if (y > PlayerSprite.y) {
        y = y - ySpeed + backgroundspeed;
    }
    if (y == PlayerSprite.y) {
        y = y + backgroundspeed;
    }

}
```

I tried it with including following code into the getDireciton() method and added the ArrayList zombieSpriteList into the ZombieSprite class, too.

```
            theGameView.getZombieSpriteList();
    theGameView.zombieSpriteList = zombieSpriteList;
    for (ZombieSprite thezombiesprite : zombieSpriteList) {

    }
```

Comment: What's the question? And why set a value to itself? Also, you probably don't want to just compare x values, since sprites presumably have a size. I'd consider using a library with collision detection baked in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the method equal(Object obj) .

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o instanceof ZombieSprite)
        return ((ZombieSprite)o).x == this.x;
    return super.equals(o);
}
```

Then if you want to check if a zoombiesprite exists in theGameView.zombieSpriteList or not ( by x value)

```
theGameView.zombieSpriteList.contains(...)
```

Comment: +1. Also, it's important to always override hashcode() whenever you override equals() in Java. See: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074996/hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java-object---a-pragmatic-concept.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check both `x` and `y`. What you can do is create a two-dimensional array that represents your `N x M grid`. The indices of the array are the `x` , `y` coordinates. So when a zombie moves, check if `grid[x,y]` is occupied. If it is not, mark that space and remove the previous `grid[x,y]` value.